# Shortest path through certain vertex in directed graph

Tags: algorithm

Say we have a strongly connected directed graph G (V,E) with positive edge weights and V0 belongs to V. Write an algorithm to find the shortest paths between all pairs of nodes through V0

An interview question. Clearly we could use Bellman-Ford which takes O(VE).

However there must exist a better solution. Any help please?

Comment: Bellman Ford is single source so all pairs with Bellman Ford will take O(V^2E), which in worst case can go up to O(V^4). All pairs shortest path can be done with Floyd-Warshall @ O(V^3).

Comment: Search for All Pairs Shortest Path on Google. There are quite a number of interesting results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could even use Dijkstra's algorithm. Run it once to find the shortest paths from V0 to all other vertices and then once more to find the shortest path from every other vertex to V0 (this is the same as running regular Dijkstra on the graph with reversed edges). Then for any pair (V1,V2) concatenate paths from V1 to V0 and from V0 to V2.

Comment: Note that path found by this method might not be *simple*, if it is an issue. (The question says nothing about it, but if it has any importance to future readers).

Comment: Correct. However, even the existence of a simple path from V1 to V2 through V0 is not guaranteed.

Comment: It is guaranteed by strong connectivity.